# why angular material select drop go behind the bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

after modal popup when i try to select something select drop goes behind the modal can any one help me to solve this problem............??

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
                    <mat-select>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
                            {{food.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Usually it means some z-index problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.modal-body .mat-form-field{
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```